# Predicting the dividend dates and dividend amount

Tags: r, predictive-models

I have the following data showing the past records of dividends paid by a company. What should be the best statistical method to predict the future dividend dates and the dividend amount?

```
dividends_dt <- structure(list(ex_date = c("2021-08-06", "2021-05-07", "2021-02-05", 
"2020-11-06", "2020-08-07", "2020-05-08", "2020-02-07", "2019-11-07", 
"2019-08-09", "2019-05-10", "2019-02-08", "2018-11-08", "2018-08-10", 
"2018-05-11", "2018-02-09", "2017-11-10", "2017-08-10", "2017-05-11", 
"2017-02-09", "2016-11-03", "2016-08-04", "2016-05-05", "2016-02-04", 
"2015-11-05", "2015-08-06", "2015-05-07", "2015-02-05", "2014-11-06", 
"2014-08-07", "2014-05-08", "2014-02-06", "2013-11-06", "2013-08-08", 
"2013-05-09", "2013-02-07", "2012-11-07", "2012-08-09", "1995-11-21", 
"1995-08-16", "1995-05-26", "1995-02-13", "1994-11-18", "1994-08-15", 
"1994-05-27", "1994-02-07", "1993-11-19", "1993-08-16", "1993-05-28", 
"1993-02-12", "1992-11-30", "1992-08-17", "1992-06-01", "1992-02-14", 
"1991-11-18", "1991-08-19", "1991-05-20", "1991-02-15", "1990-11-16", 
"1990-08-20", "1990-05-21", "1990-02-16", "1989-11-17", "1989-08-21", 
"1989-05-22", "1989-02-17", "1988-11-21", "1988-08-15", "1988-05-16", 
"1988-02-12", "1987-11-17", "1987-08-10", "1987-05-11"), frequency = c(4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), cash_amount = c(0.22, 0.22, 0.205, 0.205, 
0.205, 0.205, 0.1925, 0.1925, 0.1925, 0.1925, 0.1825, 0.1825, 
0.1825, 0.1825, 0.1575, 0.1575, 0.1575, 0.1575, 0.1425, 0.1425, 
0.1425, 0.1425, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.1175, 0.1175, 0.1175, 
0.1175, 0.1089285714, 0.1089285714, 0.1089285714, 0.1089285714, 
0.0946428571, 0.0946428571, 0.0946428571, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 
0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 
0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 
0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 
0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0010714286, 0.0009821429, 
0.0009821429, 0.0009821429, 0.0009821429, 0.0008928572, 0.0008928572, 
0.0008928572, 0.0008928572, 0.0007142857, 0.0007142857, 0.0007142857, 
0.0007142857, 0.0005357143, 0.0005357143)), row.names = c(NA, 
-72L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

       ex_date frequency  cash_amount
 1: 2021-08-06         4 0.2200000000
 2: 2021-05-07         4 0.2200000000
 3: 2021-02-05         4 0.2050000000
 4: 2020-11-06         4 0.2050000000
 5: 2020-08-07         4 0.2050000000
 6: 2020-05-08         4 0.2050000000
 7: 2020-02-07         4 0.1925000000
 8: 2019-11-07         4 0.1925000000
...
...
```

Any help will be greatly appreicated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not amenable to statistical analysis or prediction. For time series prediction you need an underlying stable generating mechanism. Profits, the decision to pay a dividend and the amount are affected by a host of factors hardly stable. Think only of the recent pandemics. No method that neglects those factors has much chance in my view.

Comment: Yes, the pandemics was a blue swan event and still, many dividend-paying companies kept dividends intact. This is an era of too much liquidity and I don't think there is any going back now unless Keynesian economics fails completely. Probably, the easy monetary policy cannot be rolled back without crashing markets. Does that mean I need to program for continuously increasing dividends unless the market crashes and then, what will happen to dividends?

Answer (score 1):

Points to consider without any sophisticated analysis

- You have a 17 year gap (no dividends?) and a change of orders of magnitude either side of the gap, so the earlier data is probably not helpful.
- The dates are effectively quarterly, probably restricted to working days.
- The amounts come in equal batches of four, as if there is an annual amount equally divided across the quarters.
- So a reasonable prediction is that the next two will be $0.22$ near November 5 or 8 and near February 7.
- For the following four dividends you need to extrapolate, and it would not surprise me if it was something like $0.2325$ if recent past trends continue, but could easily be something else.
- The world can change dramatically in the future, as shown the examples of a 17 year gap in the past, and the 21 quarters of flat dividends in the distant past

Comment: Thanks! In case the world is changing dramatically and we enter a hyperinflation cycle, what pulleys and levers can we think of adding to this dividend model to adjust for that reality? For example an era similar to the 1920s (illiquid markets) or 1940s (war-like situations). Or, we simply enter an era like the 1970s where central banks just devaluated currency by printing too much and keeping interest rates close to zero.

Comment: You can use your imagination for what might happen, being as wild as you like while remembering Cromwell's rule.   But that might look like something based on the historical data

Comment: Good point, almost anything is a possibility and it is better to not stick with any one assumption.